# How to get the array values

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display the array value from the utility library in a combo box in view file.
This is my utility library code

```
    class Utility
     {
   public $email_hooks = array(
    "create_user" => array(
            "name" => "New user creation",
            "keys" => array(
                "site_url" => "Site URL",
                "current_date" => "Curremt Date",
                "user_name" => "User name", 
                "name" => "Name of the user",
                "password" => "Password of user",
                "user_email"  => "Email address of new user"
            )               
        ),
    "register_user" => array(
            "name" => "New user registration",
            "keys" => array(
                "site_url" => "Site URL",
                "current_date" => "Curremt Date",
                "user_name" => "User name", 
                "name" => "Name of the user",
                "activation_url" => "Url for activation registered account",
                "user_email"  => "Email address of the user"
            )
        ),
    "forgot_password" => array(
            "name" => "Forgot Password",
            "keys" => array(
                "site_url" => "Site URL",
                "current_date" => "Curremt Date",
                "user_name" => "User name",
                "name" => "Name of the user",
                "reset_url" => "Url for resetting password",
                "user_email"  => "Email address of the user"
            )
        )
     );
   }
```

In view part i want to display only the values "New user creation","New user registration" and "Forgot Password" in the combo box.I used the following code in view file.

```
     <select id="choose">
        <option>-- Select One --</option>
        <?php
        foreach ($email_hooks as $key => $value)
        {
          foreach ($value as $value => $key)
          {
          echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$key.'</option>';
          }
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <div class="col-lg-4" id="email_tmpl"></div>
```

Then the output is "New user creation","Array", "New User Registration","Array","Forgot Password","Array".

I have one more question.When select the combo box value i want to show a div containing records like

%site_url% - Site URL
%current_date% - Curremt Date
%user_name% - User name
%name% - Name of the user
%password% - Password of user
%user_email% - Email address of new user.

I used the following code in js part

```
  $(document).ready(function () 
 {
 $('#choose').change(function(event) {
    $.post('info', { selected: $('#choose').val() },
        function(data) {
            $('#email_tmpl').html(data);
        }
    );            
   }); 

  });
```

this is controller code

```
    public function info()
{
$this->load->library('Utility');
$email_hooks = $this->utility->email_hooks;
$selected = isset($_POST['selected']) ? $_POST['selected'] : 'nothing';
//echo("This is $selected and other info");
foreach($email_hooks as $key=>$val)
{


    foreach($val['keys'] as $keys=>$value)
    {
        echo '%'.$keys.'%<br>';
    }
}

}
```

Now the output is

%site_url%
%current_date%
%user_name%
%name%
%password%
%user_email%
%site_url%
%current_date%
%user_name%
%name%
%activation_url%
%user_email%
%site_url%
%current_date%
%user_name%
%name%
%reset_url%
%user_email%

I want the output 
%site_url%
%current_date%
%user_name%
%name%
%password%
%user_email%- for New user creation

%site_url%
%current_date%
%user_name%
%name%
%activation_url%
%user_email% -for New user registration.

%site_url%
%current_date%
%user_name%
%name%
%reset_url%
%user_email% -for Forgot Password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
foreach($email_hooks as $key=>$val){
    echo $val['name'];
}
```

your select box:

```
<select>
<option>-- Select One --</option>
 <?php 
foreach($email_hooks as $key=>$val){
    echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$val['name'].'</option>';
}
?>
 </select>
```

Comment: @Ann then you can accept it as an answer by clicking on check icon.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look this you can get all value in your dropdown list

```
$utility = new Utility();
   //print_r($utility->email_hooks);
   echo "<select>
     <option>-- Select One --</option>";

   foreach($utility->email_hooks as $key => $val){
      echo '<option value="">'.$val["name"].'</option>';
       foreach($val as $k=>$v){
          //    echo '<option value="">'.$v.'</option>';
            if(is_array($v)){
            foreach($v as $k1 => $v1){
                echo '<option value="">'.$v1.'</option>';
            }
            }

       }

   }

   echo "</select>";
```